# Name of linear bijections whose transpose equals inverse

Tags: linear-transformations

What is the name of a function that is a linear bijection whose the transpose equals the inverse ? Can I call it "orthogonal" ?

Comment: Yes you can, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: But orthogonal functions have another definition, as you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_functions

Comment: Then you may prefer orthogonal operator/transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map $A$ acts on a finite-dimensional real inner product space, then it has a matrix representation with a transpose. If $A^T = A^{-1}$, you can call it orthogonal (here I abuse notation by referring to both the map and the matrix by $A$).

This generalizes to any real inner product space $(V,\langle\cdot\rangle)$, regardless of dimensionality. The actual definition of an orthogonal map is one which preserves the inner product of any two vectors $u,v \in V$:

$\langle Av, Au \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle$

We can show that the matrix condition $A^T = A^{-1}$ implies orthogonality of the map.

$A^T = A^{-1} \implies I = AA^T = A^TA$

Choose an orthonormal basis $\{ e_i \}$. Then we know $A_{ij} = \langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle$

So given the matrix entries of $I$, we must have

$\delta^i_j = I_{ij} = (A^TA)_{ij} = \langle e_i, A^TAe_j \rangle = \langle Ae_i, Ae_j \rangle = \langle A_i, A_j \rangle$

Thus the columns of $A$ such that $i \neq j$ are pair-wise orthogonal.

$\langle Au, Av \rangle = \langle u_iA_i, v_jA_j \rangle = u_iv_j\langle A_i, A_j \rangle = u_iv_j\delta^i_j = u_iv_i = \langle u,v \rangle$